# How to name ops that don't have a 'name' attribute in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load an LSTM model for inference, but there are a few ops that I cannot name so I can't access them after loading the graph.

The ops that I can't name are:

1. `state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(batched_c, batched_h)`
2. `val, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(layer, lstm_input, initial_state=state)`

I need to access `state` and `new_state`. How can you make ops like this accessible by name after restoring the graph later?

Comment: Does `tf.identity` help?